# How to get the current timestamp in epoch format in kinesis data generator template?

Tags: momentjs, amazon-kinesis

I'm working in Kinesis Data Generator (KDG) to load test my Kinesis Stream. I need to send the payload with current timestamp in epoch format. How to do it in Kinesis Data Generator?

Currently sending my data like,

```
{
  "bookOpenTime": "{{date.now}}"  // "2019-01-03T12:40:54+05:30"
}
```

What i want is like `{ "bookOpenTime": "1546409340209" }`

[Amazon Kinesis Data Generator doc](https://awslabs.github.io/amazon-kinesis-data-generator/web/help.html) says

> You can insert the current date and time into each record by including a date.now and date.utc items in your record template. The KDG uses the moment.js library for datetime formatting. Details for creating an appropriate format string for your use case can be found in the moment.js documentation

How to use `moment().valueOf()` in KDG Templating or any other method to achieve this?

Note: I followed below link to setup KDG and able to send the test data to my Kinesis Stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm able to get the epoch timestamp in Kinesis Data Generator template.

```
{
  "bookOpenTime": "{{date.now("x")}}" //1546853594239
}
```

Note: `x` was added in version 2.0.0.

Moment.js Doc: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/